# Stack smashing error while creating n-aray tree in c

Tags: c, binary-tree

I'm currently working on a project to create an AI in chess. There are two parts, one in python (which is not interesting for the problem) and one in C. I want to create an n-aray tree to simulate each move in the game with every possibility with à given depth.  I have created two structures for that. Information that contains every information on the game.
Game that contains Information, link to the parent, link to brother and link to its son.

U64 is an unsigned long long int.

Here are the strutures:

```c
typedef struct{
    U64* board;
    int* state;
    float note;
    int depths;
}Information;

typedef struct node{
    Information information;
    struct node* son;
    struct node* parent;
    struct node* brother;
    
}Game;
```

Here is where I create theses structures:

```c
Information malloc_information(U64 board[12], int state[6], int depths, int note){
    Information information;
    information.board = board;
    information.state = state;
    information.depths = depths;
    information.note = note;
    return information;
}

Game* malloc_game(Game* parent, Information information){
    Game* game = malloc(sizeof(Game));
    game->information = information;
    game->parent = parent;
    game->son = NULL;
    game->brother = NULL;
    return game;
}

void add_brother(Game* game, Game* brother){
    Game* tmp = game;
    while(tmp->brother != NULL){
        tmp = tmp->brother;
    }
    tmp->brother = brother;
}
```

And the function where they are called:

```c
void create_tree(Game* parent, U64 board[12],int state[6], int depths, Bishop bishops[64], Rook rooks[64], U64 pawn_movements[2][64], U64 pawn_attacks[2][64], U64 knight_attacks[64], U64 king_attacks[64]){
    if(depths == 0){
        return ;
    }
    /*not important for the problem*/
    U64 occupancy[3];
    Moves* moves = malloc_moves();
    reload_occupancy(board, occupancy);
    reload_attacks(moves, state, board, occupancy, bishops, rooks, pawn_attacks, pawn_movements, knight_attacks, king_attacks);

    for(int i=0; i<moves->len; i++){
        printf("adding node: %d, %d, %d\n", i, moves->len, depths);
        U64 next_board[12];
        int next_state[6];
        U64 next_occupancy[3];

        copy_board(board, next_board);
        copy_state(state, next_state);
        reload_occupancy(next_board, next_occupancy);
        make_move(next_board, next_occupancy, moves->moves[i], next_state);

        /* Here is where the problem should be*/
        Information information = malloc_information(next_board, next_state, depths, 0);
        Game* next_move = NULL;
        next_move = malloc_game(parent, information);
        if(parent->son == NULL){
            parent->son = next_move;
        }
        else{
            add_brother(parent->son, next_move);
        }
        create_tree(next_move, next_board, next_state, depths-1, bishops, rooks, pawn_movements, pawn_attacks, knight_attacks, king_attacks);
    }
    free_moves(moves);
}
```

After several trials, I still have the same problem. I  got **stack smashing detected**. After some research, I figured out that it was about memory allocation. However, I can’t figure out where the problem is. I tried some research there too but I didn't find something that really fit with my problem(I may have missed it, if that’s the case I’m sorry). If someone has an idea, it would be really helpful.

Best regard.
Yert.

Comment: how do we test this?

Comment: Run your program under Valgrind or use AddressSanitizer to help track down issues like this. You are likely writing outside the bounds of an array or using a pointer to a local variable that has gone out of scope. Consider putting together a [mcve] with hardcoded data to demonstrate the issue and add that code to the question.

Comment: stack smashing is not about memory allocation, its about running off the end of local stack variables, typicall due to writing outside the bounds of an array

Comment: at a very quick-glance it looks like you are solving a generalized chess game which is NP-hard, so creating a full decision tree is very naturally going to risk a buffer overflow. I looked it up and apparently chess can be solved in polynomial time but it is very complicated.

Comment: there is no way we can help you with the code shown, none of the major functions are shown (copy_state, realod_occupancy,...). You seem to have decided that the problem is to do with malloc (which it is not) and so only show functions to do with malloc

Comment: `malloc_information` makes me nervous. You're storing pointers to passed-in arrays. If those arrays every go out of scope, your pointers point to nothing. And on further inspection those arrays go out of scope every iteration of the `for` loop.

Comment: @yano Those arrays go out of scope almost immediately when the current iteration of the loop ends. I feel like that's very likely the problem too.

Comment: @pm100 Yes, I though this would be enough to understand the problem. I didnt want to overload my post with all the functions. I'm sorry if the post isn't clear enough.

Comment: @HershJoshi Yes, however, I want to add an alpha beta prunning algoritm later. I just wanted to see if the tree's creation worked before that.

Comment: @yano I think you are rigth. That might be the problem. Does that mean that I should create and store every pointers before the loop ?

Comment: it means your memory needs to stay in scope and remain valid for as long as you need it. How you go about doing that is up to your design as the programmer. I don't know enough about what you're doing here... if you move those arrays outside the loop, then the same two will be used for every call to `malloc_information`, and when `create_tree` returns, they will again go out of scope. Maybe that's ok, maybe it isn't. If those data structures need to persist to other function calls, you must `malloc` them or put them in global/static storage.

Comment: Yes, it _is_ the out-of-scope issue. Based on the in-loop call: `malloc_information(next_board, next_state, depths, 0);` all three of the arguments can _not_ be on the stack. They must be malloc'ed [AFAICT] because they must persist as _unique_ addresses beyond the completion of the loop.

Comment: @yano Okay, thank you very much. At least now I have an idea of the problem. I'll try to find a solution. Best regards.

Comment: @CraigEstey Thank you for your answer. Indeed, I'll try to store them.

Comment: You can do: `U64 *next_board = malloc(sizeof(*next_board) * 12);` and similar. You'll need a new function `free_information` that does `free` on the newly allocated members and the struct pointer itself.

Comment: You'll need: `Information *information = malloc_information();` and change the function to allocate and return a _pointer_ to the struct